# How GC1 allocates objects if size of object bigger than fixed-size region and less than half of the fixed-size region?

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, allocation

Looking at the documentation 
[oracle gc1 description](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc.html)
I have not found an answer how GC1 algorithm allocates memory for objects which size is bigger than region size for example from 1% to 20%. It's written that for objects bigger than half of the region size will be allocated like Humongous Object.
Logically it should also use more than one region. But:

> 1) How close should they be? Should they be contiguous?
>
> 2) Can other objects be located  in the region, fitted to the rest of
>   the region size, where second part of object located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How close should they be? Should they be contiguous?

- Objects that occupy more space than half a region size are considered
  humongous objects. They are directly allocated in special **humongous**
  **regions**, which are free, **contiguous regions** that are immediately made
  part of the Tenured generation (rather than Eden).

The above is from a note in Optimizing Java book on G1 gc. The humongous regions is continuous.

Can other objects be located in the region, fitted to the rest of the region size, where second part of object located?

The below documentation for the second answer is from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc_tuning.html#humongous

- Because each individual set of *StartsHumongous* and *ContinuesHumongous*
  regions contains just one humongous object, the space between the end
  of the humongous object and the end of the last region spanned by the
  object is unused. For objects that are just slightly larger than a
  multiple of the heap region size, this unused space can cause the
  heap to become fragmented.

Based on the documentation above, no other objects will be allocated in the space.

Comment: Hi! That you have pointed written in the oracle doc. But I mean If size of the Object is greater not exactly 50% of region size. For example region size is 4Mb, but size of the object is 5Mb. Size of the object is greater only on 25% of the region. According docs - it doesn't match to the condition more than 50%(half a region size).

Comment: It is clear in the documentation. The space after the ContinuesHumongous and theand the end of the last region spanned by the object is unused. The original size should be 50% more of the region not the excess size. The excess size keep continuing in the next region.